# PowerShell Error The command line is too long

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, servicenow

I am working on PowerShell script that requires me to pass string as param. The string is a comma seperated list of user names. I get the error when i have 100+ user names. But i get no error if the string has less then 100 users. See below. I have tried to pass this value using array with no luck. What is the character limitation for this param and how can i solve this. I am using this in ServiceNow Run PowerShell script. That value of the parameter is passed by ServiceNow using a comma seperated value.

```
Param(
    [string]$itil_users_a = "A.Syafiq,Aaron.Brown,Aaron.Reynnie,Abd.Jalil,Abdu.Hijazi,Abdul.Onny,Abdullah.Ammar,Abel.Muataco"    
    )
```

Comment: You have a trailing square bracket. Is that a typo? Where are you calling this script from?

Comment: I ask because this should not be a PowerShell limitation but a cmd.exe one maybe. Also you could consider using text file input for something like this.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, i have corrected it. I am using this in ServiceNow Run PowerShell script. That value of the parameter is passed by ServiceNow using a comma seperated value.

Comment: Command line length is usually determined by the caller.  How are you launching the script?  A batch file has a shorter limit than a powershell script.

Comment: Do you have an example of the error text?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843611/powershell-to-avoid-cmd-8191-character-limit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be running into the maximum length for command lines - 8191 chars.  See this [KB article on max command line length](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was experiencing. I just thought for Power Shell, it may not be the case. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: it's really a shame that still with Windows 10, one has to face such limitation.

Comment: any ideas about getting round this that aren't just breaking up the command?

Comment: Has anyone else tried using Powershell in Windows Terminal to run longer commands? I tried that earlier today for a command that was >9000 characters long, and from what I recall it succeeded when run there. It would be odd if Windows Terminal found a way to bypass that limit though, so maybe I'm remembering wrong.

Comment: This answer was posted in 2015 and it's 2021 now. Is there any update on how to get around this problem?

Comment: @Ray You can use pipe to get around this. See my answer for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **pipe** to get around this.

I can insert a million rows to sqlite3.exe using pipe.

Rather than `sqlite.exe .\ex1.db $sql` which will return ***error***. You can use this: `$sql | sqlite.exe .\ex1.db`

The $sql variable can have more than a million rows (so it's more than 8191 characters).