# Powershell to avoid cmd 8191 character limit

Tags: powershell, cmd, max

I'm creating a PowerShell that runs a simple Java program using:

```
Start-Process -filepath .\java.exe -ArgumentList "Input" -NoNewWindow
```

The Input class in this case simply accepts and prints a string.

I'm expecting strings with length greater than the `cmd.exe` 8191 char limit, so I need to run it in PS.

Current scenario:

- Running the above command in the PS directly works and `Input` accepts string greaters than 8191 char.
- Saving the command in a ps1 file and run it, a PS windows appears but cmd runs behind the scene as it hits the 8191 character limit.

I tried adding `-Wait` as well, but not luck.

Any idea?

Comment: Both right-clicking/run with powershell on the ps1 script and from another ps1 file using `Invoke-Expression .\javaRun.ps1`. If I invoke java.exe directly, without `Start-Process` I still hit the 8191 char limit.

Comment: I tried the `Invoke-Expression` only in order to find a workaround, I'd like to stick to a single script. Why the only wait is to run the script or the actual command within the PS? I don't know much about Windows but it sounds a silly behaviour. How come running a PS script it uses the cmd underneath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you state, the max. length of an *interactive* command line ***in `cmd.exe`*** (at the interactive Command Prompt, but *not* in batch files) is officially **`8,191` characters** - see [the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation).
If you try to submit a command line via the Run dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>), the limit appears to be even lower.

However, this does *not* apply to command lines ***in PowerShell***, - neither at the interactive prompt nor in `.ps1` files - where the limit is much higher - **`32,764` characters**.<sup>[1]</sup>

In other words: **commands launched *from within* PowerShell are *not* subject to the `8,191`-character limit** (unless they themselves impose their own limit, which a call to `cmd.exe /c` does, for instance) - irrespective of whether you use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) or [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (neither of which you should use for invoking console applications / scripts - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375)) or by *direct invocation* (by file path, possibly preceded by `&`, the call operator - e.g., `.\javaRun.ps1` or `& .\javaRun.ps1`) - none of these methods involve `cmd.exe`

As for **calling *external programs* from PowerShell**:

- .NET-based executables and most natively compiled executables *are* capable of receiving command lines up to PowerShell's `32,764`-character limit.
- By contrast, if the target executable happens to be `cmd.exe` (a command line executed via `cmd /c`), *it* again imposes the overall `8,191`-character limit. (However, in *batch files* - `.cmd`, `.bat` - that limit only applies to `cmd.exe`'s *internal* (built-in) commands, such as `echo`; calls to external programs are actually allowed to be `32,766` chars. long).
- I don't know about executables using *different runtimes*, such as `java.exe`; but if *they* turn out to be the bottleneck, you won't be able to overcome this problem from PowerShell, and will instead have to find a different way to pass input to the target program, such as via standard input or an aux. file.

---

<sup>[1] I don't have an official reference, but you can **verify the limit experimentally** as follows: `C:\Windows\system32\choice.exe /d y /t 0 /m ('x' * (32764-44)) 2>$null`. `-44` subtracts the length of the static prefix of the command, and creates as many `x` chars. as needed to amount to an overall command-line length of line is `32,764`. The call succeeds (in the sense that it is *successfully submitted* and `choice.exe` is actually invoked, irrespective of whether it then reports an error or not), and produces no output (there's incidental *stderr* output, which `2>$null` discards). If you increase the length by only 1 character (change `-44` to `-43`), the invocation breaks *fundamentally* with "Program 'choice.exe' failed to run: The filename or extension is too long".

**Presumably, the limit is ultimately imposed by the [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) WinAPI function**, whose docs state: "The maximum length of this string is `32,767` characters, including the Unicode terminating null character". However, even taking the extra terminating null character that is used behind the scenes into account, `37,764 + 1` is `32,765`, and I don't know what accounts for the remaining `2` characters.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I tried other ways to understand how this works. It seems that running `Start-Process Powershell` in a ps1 file, does not hit the char limit. It's been hit when from the same opened new shell, java is called. But how can Java could be the bottleneck if running it with -NoNewWindow works? Windows/PS design is doing something that I can't fully understand.

Comment: @user219378 If you don't hit the limit with `Start-Process -NoNewWindow`, then you won't hit it with direct invocation either (`.\java.exe ...`), which you should use instead. I was only _speculating_ about `java.exe` being the limitation, as the only plausible explanation for why it wouldn't work from PowerShell as described in the answer. From `cmd.exe` / a batch file you _will_ hit the limit, irrespective of what executable you call. I'm unclear on what you're still unclear on.

Comment: @user219378: Are you perhaps trying to do something like `Start-Process .\javaRun.ps1 ...`? That will perform the default GUI shell verb, Open, on the _document_ that the `.ps1` file is from the system's perspective - and then whatever action is defined via the registry will be performed - which _could_ involve `cmd.exe` - depending on your machine's configuration. Instead, use `Start-Process powershell.exe -Args '-NoExit -File .\javaRun.ps1 ...'` for predictable invocation, _if_ you need the script to run in a new window (if not, use direct invocation).

Comment: To recap: if I use `Start-Process Powershell` I don't hit the limit, from the same shell if I run `.\java.exe Input` I hit the limit. Insted, from the same shell using `Start-Process .\java.exe Input -NoNewWindows` works. I'd simply like to make the latter work from a ps1, but I I use the same command in a ps1, I hit the limit. And this it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Probably a better question now it would be, how I can ensure that `.\java.exe` is not the bottleneck and/or how it gets called from Windows?

Comment: I've just noticed that the only one that worked with the `-NoNewWindows` is just giving me the impressiont that it does. But the java application is not accepting the input correctly when pasting a long string. If I call Java without the `Start-Process` it opens a new conhost.exe and java in a cmd windows. I hate it.

Comment: The sysinternal Process Explorer tells me that using both 'Start-Process' with `-NoNewWindows` and calling `.\java.exe` directly, it opens a process within the PS without opening a new conhost.exe. If I don't include `-NoNewWindows` it does open a new conhost.exe under java.exe. Still it looks all under the powershell.exe tree. So @mklement0 you might be right, java could be the limitation here. No idea how to prove it yet.

Comment: @user219378. Yes, `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` and direct execution run in the caller's console window, by design. `Start-Process` without  `-NoNewWindow` indeed creates a new console window, but it's still a _child process_ of the caller's process - and it does _not_ involve `cmd.exe` - it is `java.exe` that directly runs in that window. I don't have Java, but I can tell you that a .NET-based executable works fine in all these situations.

Comment: Do you have a source for this PowerShell command limit? Searching for that information is what got me here.

Comment: @Sled, please see the footnote I've just added.