# Converting .ps1 to .bat doesn't cause cmd.exe to hit max character length - but why?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Based on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843611/powershell-to-avoid-cmd-8191-character-limit) and some Googling/testing, it is pretty clear that the maximum length of a command line in `cmd.exe` is `8,191` characters. However...my script seems to successfully exceed that length, and I can't figure out why it works.

So I have:

- A script written/saved as a `.ps1`
- I'm *converting* it to a `.bat` using the method from [Converting PowerShell to Batch](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/converting-powershell-to-batch)
- If I run the `.bat` - there don't seem to be any issues
- If I try to echo the `$encoded` command or just remove `@echo off` before running the `.bat` - it is easy to see that the length/content of `$encoded` has been truncated...yet it works as expected

I realize this is a bit of a strange question since I'm trying to ascertain some kind of hidden truth about something that works vs. something that is broken, but I'd like to understand *why* it is working!

**Note:**
The primary reason I'm creating a `.bat` for my script is because I have a number of small 'programs' that I need to run on my work computer and share with others. Our company's execution policies don't allow running scripts, and it is much easier for others to use something I've written if it is a `.bat` since they won't need to understand/use `PowerShell`. They can just place the `.bat` in the right place, give it two clicks, and then sit back and relax until something happens.

**EDIT:** Here's the truncated command in the `cmd.exe` window. If I convert from Base64 back to readable text, it is clearly missing about half of the script. Yet - I'm not noticing any problems
[image: Truncated Command]

Comment: The script can be a million characters long, but the _command line_ (including arguments) cannot exceed 8191 chars. Even though your script is 10K chars, the command line for the process will still just be `powershell -File myscript.ps1` <- which in itself is obviously under the limit

Comment: Right - but in this case, I'm not calling a `.ps1` because it wouldn't be able to run, so here are the first 200 or so characters from my command line: `powershell.exe -NoExit -encodedCommand ZgB1AG4AYwB0AGkAbwBuACAAVwByAGkAdABlAC0ASABvAHMAdABQAHIAbwBtAHAAdAAgAHsADQAKACAAIAAgACAAWwBDAG0AZABsAGUAdABCAGkAbgBkAGkAbgBnACgAKQBdAA0ACgAgACAAIAAgAHAAYQByAGEA...` it goes on and it looks like the full string is `14,488` which should be well over the limit

Comment: And you're launching this 14488 char long command directly from `cmd.exe`?

Comment: It is a .bat so the code in the .bat itself is: `@echo off
powershell.exe -NoExit -encodedCommand ZgB1AG4AYwB0AGkAbwBuACAAVwByAGkAdABlAC0ASABvAHMAdABQAHIAbwBtAHAAdAAgAHsADQAKACAAIAAgACAAWwBDAG0AZABsAGUAdABCAGkAbgBkAGkAbgBnACgAKQBdAA0ACgAgACAAIAAgAHAAYQByAGEAbQANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAoAA0ACgAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIwAgAEMAYQBwAHQAaQBvAG4AIAB0AG8AIABwAHIAZQBjAGUAZQBk...` you get the idea. I'll add a screenshot, but if you remove @echo off then you can clearly see the prompt cutoff early (and I decoded what was there, it was only part of the script), yet it seems to work fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The `8191`-character limit applies to the *interactive command line* and calls to `cmd.exe`'s *CLI* (via `cmd /c`)
- It does *not* apply to commands invoked *from batch files* - there the limit is close to<sup>[1]</sup> `32KiB` (`32,768`) characters.

  - However, it still seems to apply selectively to `cmd.exe`'s *internal* commands, such as `echo`; by contrast, a call to an *external program* such as `powershell.exe` is not affected (though it is possible for specific external programs to have their own, lower limits).

---

As an aside:

As clever as the [linked method of **converting PowerShell scripts to batch files**](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/converting-powershell-to-batch) is, **the resulting batch files *lack support for arguments* to be passed through to the PowerShell code**, and adding support for that would be impractical (it would require Base64-encoding the arguments too, *at invocation time*, which isn't possible from a batch file except with the help of non-built-in utilities).

- If your script / batch file is written to either require no arguments on invocation or to prompt for them interactively (as in your case), this limitation is not a concern.
- However, **you may want argument support for any of the following reasons**:

  - To allow calling the batch file from `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt) *with arguments*.
  - To allow calling with arguments from other environments that support passing arguments, notably Task Scheduler and the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>).
  - To make the batch file support drag-and-drop (which implicitly passes the dropped files' paths as arguments).

As for the **overall reason to wrap PowerShell code in batch files**:

- Batch files (`.cmd`, `.bat`) can be launched *directly*, as if they were executables, *system-wide*.
- By contrast, this is *not* supported for PowerShell scripts (`.ps1`), which from outside PowerShell must be invoked via an explicit call to the PowerShell CLI; note that systems may be configured to categorically prevent execution of `.ps1` scripts - see next section.

---

**If you *do* need argument support in your batch file**, the best - but inconvenient - solution is to **distribute *two* files**:

- the original `*.ps1` file...
- and a *companion batch file*, with the *same base file name*, to be placed in the *same directory* - which can be invoked from *outside* PowerShell - whose sole purpose is to invoke the `*.ps1` file via `powershell.exe` with pass-through arguments.

E.g. `foo.cmd` would accompany `foo.ps1`, with the following - invariant - content:

```
@powershell.exe -NoProfile -File "%~dpn0.ps1" %*
```

Note:

- **Important**: The above assumes that the effective PowerShell [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) allows execution of script files (`.ps1`).

  - If you cannot make this assumption, place `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` before `-NoProfile` above (or, to deactivate all checks, `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`), but note that an execution policy based on  *GPO* (Group Policy Objects) may still prevent script execution.
- To call *PowerShell (Core) 7+* instead, use `pwsh.exe` instead of `powershell.exe`.
- `%~dpn0` expands to the full path of the enclosing batch file itself *without its filename extension*; appending `.ps1` therefore targets the companion PowerShell script in the same directory; run `cmd /c call /?` for an explanation of the syntax.
- `%*` passes any and all arguments received by the batch file on.

---

<sup>[1] In practice, the limits appear to be: `32,767` characters *in batch files*, and - lower by 3 chars. - `32,764` for *Powershell* (both on the command line / via the CLI and in `*.ps1` scripts). In PowerShell, the limit may in practice be even lower than that, because PowerShell expands the names of executables it locates via `$env:PATH` to their *full paths* in the command lines constructed behind the scenes, which `cmd.exe` doesn't do.</sup>

Comment: Could you possibly expand on the content of `foo.ps1` or how arguments would get passed to and through `foo.cmd` in your example? I know that `%*` will expand to represent all arguments passed to `foo.cmd`; but does the header of `foo.ps1` need to parse `arg[n]`? Also, how/when would arguments be passed to `foo.cmd` in the first place? Dropping files onto a `.bat` is one way, but alternatively - would this method imply calling `foo.cmd`/`foo.bat` from a shell with arguments to begin with? If so, what does that look like and, importantly, how does `foo.ps1` handle the expanded form of `%*`?

Comment: @immobile2, please see my update, also re execution policies. Re `%*`: It is just a pass-through mechanism, so your `.ps1` file should handle arguments the way it always does, as in direct invocation (use `$args` if you don't want to declare parameters explicitly, but preferably use a `param(...)` block to declare them) - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters)