# .ps1 script reported as "Missing closing '}'" in .bat file script

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am having difficuty converting a short PowerShell script into a cmd.exe .bat file script. The error message (see below) complains of a `Missing closing '}'. The .ps1 script runs successfully as expected.

I used SEMICOLON characters at the end of assignment statements. I escaped the VERTICAL LINE (pipe) character with a CARET (^). What am I missing?

Here is the .bat script and error message output.

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content -Path .\DistributeFiles2.bat
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$ProjectPath = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\Project';" ^
    "$NFilesPerDirectory = 400;" ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Path (Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\images') -Filter '*.jpeg' ^|" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "# Check to see if the filename starts with four (4) digits.;" ^
            "if ($_.BaseName -match '^(\d{4}).*') {" ^
                "$FolderNumber = [math]::Floor([int]$Matches[1] / $NFilesPerDirectory);" ^
                "$FolderName = 'Folder' + $FolderNumber.ToString();" ^
                "$FolderPath = Join-Path -Path $ProjectPath -ChildPath $FolderName;" ^
                "# If the destination directory does not exist, create it.;" ^
                "if (-not (Test-Path -Path $FolderPath)) { mkdir $FolderPath -WhatIf ^| Out-Null }" ^
                "# Move the file to the destination directory.;" ^
                "Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $FolderPath -WhatIf" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```

Back in a cmd.exe shell...

```
C:>DistributeFiles2.bat

 9:55:41.67  C:\src\t
C:>powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command     "$ProjectPath = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\Project';"     "$NFilesPerDirectory = 400;"     "Get-ChildItem -File -Path (Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\images') -Filter '*.jpeg' ^|"         "ForEach-Object {"             "# Check to see if the filename starts with four (4) digits.;"             "if ($_.BaseName -match '^(\d{4}).*') {"                 "$FolderNumber = [math]::Floor([int]$Matches[1] / $NFilesPerDirectory);"                 "$FolderName = 'Folder' + $FolderNumber.ToString();"                 "$FolderPath = Join-Path -Path $ProjectPath -ChildPath $FolderName;"                 "# If the destination directory does not exist, create it.;"                 "if (-not (Test-Path -Path $FolderPath)) { mkdir $FolderPath -WhatIf ^| Out-Null }"                 "# Move the file to the destination directory.;"                 "Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $FolderPath -WhatIf"             "}"         "}"
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
```

This is the original .ps1 script which is working as expected.

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content -Path .\DistributeFiles.ps1
$ProjectPath = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\Project';
$NFilesPerDirectory = 400;
Get-ChildItem -File -Path (Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\images') -Filter '*.jpeg' |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Check to see if the filename starts with four (4) digits.;
        if ($_.BaseName -match '^(\d{4}).*') {
            $FolderNumber = [math]::Floor([int]$Matches[1] / $NFilesPerDirectory);
            $FolderName = 'Folder' + $FolderNumber.ToString();
            $FolderPath = Join-Path -Path $ProjectPath -ChildPath $FolderName;
            # If the destination directory does not exist, create it.;
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $FolderPath)) { mkdir $FolderPath -WhatIf | Out-Null }
            # Move the file to the destination directory.;
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $FolderPath -WhatIf
        }
    }
PS C:\src\t> .\DistributeFiles.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\Project\Folder0".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\images\0000.jpeg Destination: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\Project\Folder0".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\Project\Folder1".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\images\0401.jpeg Destination: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\Project\Folder1".
```

Running the .ps1 script from a .bat file script also works as expected.

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content -Path .\DistributeFiles.bat
@powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0%~n0.ps1"

PS C:\src\t> .\DistributeFiles.bat
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\Project\Folder0".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\images\0000.jpeg Destination: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\Project\Folder0".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\Project\Folder1".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\images\0401.jpeg Destination: C:\Users\lit\Desktop\Project\Folder1".
```

**Update:**

Taking @mklement0's advice, I have removed QUOTATION MARK characters. The two (2) VERTICAL LINE (pipe) characters are escaped and the beginning-of-line CARET in the `-match` regex is escaped. I avoided using QUOTATION MARK characters in the .ps1 script from the beginning. The "Missing closing '}'" failure still occurs. What am I missing?

```
C:>powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
More?     $ProjectPath = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\Project'; ^
More?     $NFilesPerDirectory = 400; ^
More?     Get-ChildItem -File -Path (Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\images') -Filter '*.jpeg' ^| ^
More?         ForEach-Object { ^
More?             # Check to see if the filename starts with four (4) digits.; ^
More?             if ($_.BaseName -match '^^(\d{4}).*') { ^
More?                 $FolderNumber = [math]::Floor([int]$Matches[1] / $NFilesPerDirectory); ^
More?                 $FolderName = 'Folder' + $FolderNumber.ToString(); ^
More?                 $FolderPath = Join-Path -Path $ProjectPath -ChildPath $FolderName; ^
More?                 # If the destination directory does not exist, create it.; ^
More?                 if (-not (Test-Path -Path $FolderPath)) { mkdir $FolderPath -WhatIf ^| Out-Null }; ^
More?                 # Move the file to the destination directory.; ^
More?                 Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $FolderPath -WhatIf; ^
More?             }; ^
More?         };
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
```

**Update 2:**

With @mklement0's consistently good advice, here is the working code.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    $ProjectPath = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\Project'; ^
    $NFilesPerDirectory = 400; ^
    Get-ChildItem -File -Path (Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\images') -Filter '*.jpeg' ^| ^
        ForEach-Object { ^
            ^<# Check to see if the filename starts with four (4) digits.#^> ^
            if ($_.BaseName -match '^^(\d{4}).*') { ^
                $FolderNumber = [math]::Floor([int]$Matches[1] / $NFilesPerDirectory); ^
                $FolderName = 'Folder' + $FolderNumber.ToString(); ^
                $FolderPath = Join-Path -Path $ProjectPath -ChildPath $FolderName; ^
                ^<# If the destination directory does not exist, create it.#^> ^
                if (-not (Test-Path -Path $FolderPath)) { mkdir $FolderPath -WhatIf ^| Out-Null }; ^
                ^<# Move the file to the destination directory.#^> ^
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $FolderPath -WhatIf; ^
            }; ^
        };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In **`cmd.exe`** and therefore also in batch files, **`^` only acts as the escape character in *unquoted* strings**; therefore, in general you do *not* need to escape `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `|` inside `"..."` strings as `^|` - if you do, the `^` characters are *retained*.
- However, **it looks like using `cmd.exe`'s line continuation (a *line-ending* `^`) with *double-quoted-per-line strings* doesn't work robustly**<sup>[1]</sup> (and having a single double-quoted string span multiple lines is fundamentally unsupported), so the solution is to **use *unquoted* lines**, on which you *do* need to escape `|` as `^|`, among other characters.

Here's an example that exercises various PowerShell syntax constructs:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
  [Environment]::CommandLine; ^
  $ProjectPath = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\Project'; ^
  ^<# This is a comment - note the required *inline* comment syntax #^> ^
  $ProjectPath ^| ^
    ForEach-Object { \"[$ProjectPath]\" }; ^
  (42).ToString(); ^
  \"A & B\"
```

<sup>Note the inclusion of **`[Environment]::CommandLine;`** as the first statement, which will echo the command line as seen by PowerShell, which can help with troubleshooting. As an aside: When using PowerShell (Core) 7+'s CLI, `pwsh.exe`, rather than Windows PowerShell's `powershell.exe`, the command line reported is a *reconstructed* form that is not guaranteed to reflect the actual command line used; notably, `""` sequences turn to `\"`.</sup>

Note:

- **Each internal line must have `^` as the *very last* character** on the line.
- Because line continuation doesn't include the newline, **`;` must be used to explicitly terminate each PowerShell statement** (except the last).

  - Note: Inserting *a blank line* (without ending it in `^`) between statements does *not* work: while it does technically result in an actual newline when passed to PowerShell, the absence of overall double-quoting makes PowerShell treat such newlines the same as *spaces*, which therefore still necessitates `;` between statements.
  - It is for this reason that single-line comments (`# ...`) are *not* supported with this invocation method, given that such comments *invariably span the rest of the line*, with no support for `;` to end them - see next point.
- **In order to include *comments*, the form `^<# ... #^>` - i.e. (escaped) *inline* comments must be used** - normal single-line comments (`# ....`) are *not* supported (see previous point).
- **`cmd.exe`'s metacharacters need individual `^`-escaping**, namely:

  - `& | < > ^`
  - Additionally, *if called from a `for /f` statement*:

    - `= , ; ( )`
- **`"` characters must be escaped as `\"`** so that *PowerShell* treats them as part of the command(s) to execute (otherwise they get stripped during command-line parsing); therefore, **when feasible, using `'...'` (single-quoting) is easier**.

  - If there is only *one* or an *uneven number* of `"` chars. on an interior line, escape that one / the last one as `\^"` (sic).
  - Inside `\"...\"`, `cmd.exe` metacharacters do *not* need `^`-escaping, because `cmd.exe` sees such an escaped-for-PowerShell string as a regular double-quoted string.
  - However, whitespace normalization is applied to what is inside `\"...\"`; that is, runs of *multiple* spaces are folded into *one* space each; if that is a concern, use `^"\"...\"^"` (sic).
- For **additional information**, including a `for /f` example and how to handle escaping of `!` when `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is in effect, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66085286/45375).

---

<sup>[1] It only works if you ensure that any interior `"..."^`  line and a closing `"..."` line *starts with at least one whitespace character*. However, in most cases it will be less effort and arguably more readable *not* to double-quote the individual lines and to instead selectively `^`-escape `cmd.exe`'s metacharacters, as shown.</sup>

Comment: *N. B.:* a single double-quoted string spanning multiple lines can be achieved in `cmd.exe` when you escape the quotation marks as well like `^"`…

Comment: Thanks, @aschipfl, but in practice that amounts to additional, unnecessary work, because to `cmd.exe` the interior lines are still _unquoted_ and therefore still require `^`-escaping of `cmd.exe` metacharacters as well as line continuations. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mklement0, do you think there would be any merit to getting someone (smarter than me) to create a `ps2bat` process? I wish there were no need, but some people and organizations put up a big red line against using a PowerShell script file.

Comment: @lit, see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/69302558/45375 helps.