# extracting zip file with powershell , reading the file and then extracting value between tags

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to scripting and I have been stuck on this problem.

I want to extract a zip file and in that zip file there is a xml file called file.xml which I need to extract information from.

The file is huge and I only need to extract info between two tags.

```
<Report name="result\_many fail" summary="20" yes=19 no="1" finished=20>
```

I need to extract information between the tags name and finished and save it to a txt file.
The txt file should look like this:

```
name result_many fail, summary 20, yes 19 , no  1, finished 20
```

The problem is that it unzips to the right destination folder but it doesn't save anything into the result.txt file. My txt file is always empty.

This is my code:

```
echo "unzipping file..."
powershell "Expand-Archive C:\path_to_zip_file -Destinationpath C:\path_to_to_destination_folder;
$Path = “C:\path_to_to_destination_folder\file.xml;”
Select-Xml -XPath '//Report[@finished]').Node.InnerText;
Set-Content -Path 'C:\path_to_to_destination_folder\result.txt'

@echo "done"
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Is this the code you are actually using? It doesn't even run

Comment: You are missing to set the `-Path` to your source xml document. See the [Select-Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7.1) docs.

Comment: @SEarle1986 yeah it runs , it just extracts correctly and then stops

Comment: it failed when I tried. There is a syntax error on this line as you have a `)`  `Select-Xml -XPath '//Report[@finished]').Node.InnerText;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside incidental aspects of your question (seemingly calling from `cmd.exe` with a broken attempt to pass a multi-line command string, invalid sample XML, lack of a file argument to [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml), lack of input to the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlet):

```
$path = 'C:\path_to_to_destination_folder\file.xml'
(Select-Xml '//Report[@finished]' $path).
  Node.Attributes.ForEach({ $_.Name + ' ' + $_.Value }) -join ', ' |
    Set-Content C:\path_to_to_destination_folder\result.txt
```

To call your PowerShell code *from `cmd.exe`* (a batch file) requires you to either pass it *on a single line* or to carefully spread it across multiple lines with line-continuations, using `^`, based on the techniques described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69439031/45375):

```
@echo off

echo unzipping file...

powershell -c Expand-Archive C:\path_to_zip_file -DestinationPath C:\path_to_to_destination_folder; ^
  $path = 'C:\path_to_to_destination_folder\file.xml'; ^
  (Select-Xml '//Report[@finished]' $path). ^
    Node.Attributes.ForEach({ $_.Name + ' ' + $_.Value }) -join ', ' ^| ^
      Set-Content C:\path_to_to_destination_folder\result.txt

echo done
```

If you need help with the fundamentals, here are some **PowerShell learning resources**:

- A starting point is [Learning PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/docs/learning-powershell).
- [This series of articles](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-one-liners-help,-syntax,-display-and--files/), even though it predates PowerShell (Core) 6+, is a great, recipe-oriented introduction to PowerShell.
- http://hyperpolyglot.org/shell juxtaposes the syntax of POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` with that of `cmd.exe` and PowerShell in concise, tabular form.

Comment: i forgot to add `"Expand-Archive"`after the powershell keyword but it unzips, the result.txt file is still empty even with your code

Comment: @konoha, that applies that your XPath query doesn't find anything. Note that your XML snippet is invalid, because some attributes lack quoting. Here's an example of what would work: `Select-Xml '//Report[@finished]'  -Content '<Report name="result\_many fail" summary="20" yes="19" no="1" finished="20" />'`

Comment: Also note that if you're really calling from `cmd.exe`, even your corrected command won't work, because you cannot pass multi-line commands without using line-continuation with `^`. And the lack-of-input problems hinted at in this answer persist.

Comment: are there any resources I could look up to do this correctly? is there really a lot missing ?

Comment: thanks a lot ! I will read trough the articles and try to understand them