# How to echo if invoke-webrequest failed due to an invalid/expired url else continue download in Powershell CLI?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, invoke-webrequest

I want to use a powershell command inside a batch file to download a file.

My code looks like that and works for just downloading the file from that specific url:

```
powershell "$progresspreference='silentlycontinue'; wget -uri "https://thisismyurl.com/123456" -outfile '%userprofile%\Downloads\file.zip'"
```

Now I want to implement `echo download failed! url is invalid. & pause & goto label` **if** the `invoke-webrequest` failed due to an invalid or expired url.

Also, since the powershell commands within the batch file get pretty long, is there a way to break up the commands?

I tried

```
powershell "$progresspreference='silentlycontinue' `
wget -uri "https://thisismyurl.com/123456" -outfile '%userprofile%\Downloads\file.zip'"
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: You say that your first snippet works, but I doubt that. You would need to change ```-uri "https://thisismyurl.com/123456"``` to either ```-uri 'https://thisismyurl.com/123456'``` or ```-uri \"https://thisismyurl.com/123456\"```, for it to do so.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for your reply. I downloaded the file multiple times with the code I provided without any issues. What's the issue with using non-excluded double quotation marks for the url?

Comment: The entire command argument from `cmd.exe` to `powershell.exe` is doublequoted, therefore without one of the modifications I've suggested, the first outer doublequote will be prematurely closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're calling [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, with the implied `-Command` parameter, which means that the success status of the *last statement* in the command string determines `powershell.exe`'s exit code: `0` in the success case, `1` otherwise.

  - In Windows PowerShell, `wget` is an alias for the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-WebRequest) cmdlet, and, as with any cmdlet, if *any* error occurs during its execution, its success status is considered `$false` and therefore translates to exit code `1`.
  - Therefore, you can simply use `cmd.exe`'s `||` operator to act on the case where `powershell.exe`'s exit code is *non-zero*.
- As for *multiline* PowerShell CLI calls from a batch file, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69439031/45375). In short: you cannot use overall `"..."` enclosure and must therefore `^`-escape select characters, and you must end each interior line with `^`

To put it all together in the context of your code:

```bash
@echo off & setlocal

powershell $progresspreference='silentlycontinue'; ^
  wget -uri 'https://thisismyurl.com/123456' ^
       -outfile '%userprofile%\Downloads\file.zip' ^
  || (echo download failed! url is invalid. & pause & goto label)

exit /b 0

:label
  echo failure-handling branch...
exit /b 1
```