# Save Bcdedit Firmware to Array in Batch File

Tags: arrays, powershell, batch-file, firmware, bcdedit

Help me to create a batch script, and get the same result as this powershell script:

```
function FWList {
    $FWStore = bcdedit /enum firmware
    $FWOS = ($FWStore | select-string identifier,device,path,description) -notmatch '{fwbootmgr}'
    for ( $n=0; $n -lt $FWOS.count; $n++ ) {
        if ( $FWOS[$n] -match 'identifier' ) {
            if ( $FWOS[$($n + 1 )] -match 'device' ) {
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    des  = $FWOS[$($n + 3)].line.TrimStart('description').Trim()
                    id   = $FWOS[$n].line.Split()[-1]
                    path = $FWOS[$($n + 2)].line.Split()[-1]
                    dev  = $FWOS[$($n + 1)].line.Split()[-1]
                }
            } else {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                    des  = $FWOS[$($n + 1)].line.TrimStart('description').Trim()
                    id   = $FWOS[$n].line.Split()[-1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Example Usage
FWList | Format-List #To show in List view
FWList | Format-Table #To show in Table view
(FWList)[1..3] | Foreach {$_.des}
Pause
```

Example: "FWList | Format-List"

The output:

```
des  : Windows Boot Manager
id   : {bootmgr}
path : \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
dev  : partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3

des : ATA HDD: ADATA SU650
id  : {ed2a2e5c-bb68-11ee-89e6-806e6f6e6963}
```

In this script I can easily get value of any Firmwares saved in array.

I tried like this but confused about how to continue...

```bash
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "FWOSList=bcdedit /enum firmware ^| findstr "identifier description device path" ^| findstr /v "{fwbootmgr}""
set arr=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-4" %%a in ( `%FWOSList%` ) DO (
    if /I "%%a[%arr%]"=="identifier" set ID[%arr%]=%%b
    set /a arr+=1

)
rem get description, identifier, device, path
```

Comment: That's not how things work here. We help you with a specific problem with your batch script, after you have written, and run it. We do not offer a free code conversion service, and it is unfair to expect people to become your personal tutors.

Comment: tried and wrote but confused  to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**:

- In order for the `bcdedit /enum firmware` call at the heart of your solution to succeed, it must be run from an *elevated session*. Therefore, so must the code below.

From your own batch-file attempt it looks like you're **only** looking for the **values on the lines that start with `identifier`**, except for the line whose value is `{fwbootmgr}`.

```bash
@echo off & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Loop over all "identifier" lines of interest and store the 2nd
:: whitespace-separated token of each 
:: in individual ID[%ndx%] variables that emulate an array.
set i=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%a in (`
  bcdedit /enum firmware ^| findstr "^identifier " ^| findstr /v "{fwbootmgr}"
`) do set "ID[!i!]=%%a" & set /a i=i+1

:: Example processing:

:: Print all ID[%ndx%] variables that were created.
echo -- Resulting ID[%%ndx%%] variables:
set ID[

:: Target a specific variable, the 2nd one in this example.
set i=1
echo -- Value of ID[%i%]:
echo !ID[%i%]!
```

Note:

- If you need to ensure that no preexisting `Item[%ndx%]` variables exist, place the following before the `for /f` call:

  ```bash
  for /f "delims==" %%i in ('Set Item[ 2^>NUL') do set "%%i="
  ```

---

If you want to **capture *all* values, in *multiple* emulated arrays** each corresponding to one of the properties in the output from your PowerShell code:

- Emulating what the PowerShell code does in a batch file would be exceedingly cumbersome.
- Therefore, **call your PowerShell code *from your batch file***, via [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI.

  - While it is possible to use *multiline* PowerShell commands from a batch file, doing so requires careful escaping - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69439031/45375). The solution below therefore uses a *single-line* representation of the code in your question.
- To make parsing of the output easier for your batch file, instruct the PowerShell code to produce CSV output, using [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv).

```bash
@echo off & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (`
  powershell -NoProfile -Command "function FWList { $FWStore = bcdedit /enum firmware; $FWOS = ($FWStore | select-string identifier,device,path,description) -notmatch '{fwbootmgr}'; for ( $n=0; $n -lt $FWOS.count; $n++ ) { if ( $FWOS[$n] -match 'identifier' ) { if ( $FWOS[$($n + 1 )] -match 'device' ) { [PsCustomObject]@{ des = $FWOS[$($n + 3)].line.TrimStart('description').Trim(); id = $FWOS[$n].line.Split()[-1]; path = $FWOS[$($n + 2)].line.Split()[-1]; dev = $FWOS[$($n + 1)].line.Split()[-1]; } } else { [PsCustomObject]@{ des = $FWOS[$($n + 1)].line.TrimStart('description').Trim(); id = $FWOS[$n].line.Split()[-1] } } } } }; FWList | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1"
`) do set "DES[!i!]=%%~a" & set "ID[!i!]=%%~b" & set "PATH[!i!]=%%~c" & set "DEV[!i!]=%%~d" & set /a i=i+1

:: Example processing:

:: Print all "array variables" that were created.
echo -- Resulting DEV[%%ndx%%] variables:
set DES[
echo -- Resulting ID[%%ndx%%] variables:
set ID[
echo -- Resulting PATH[%%ndx%%] variables:
set PATH[
echo -- Resulting DEV[%%ndx%%] variables:
set DEV[
```

Comment: The code work properly. Thank for this. This another method, by calling powershell from batch.

but I'm still curious and will learn it with cmd itself without calling powershell.
so in order i have two options, the powershell method and the batch method

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Mr.Key7. You'll find that PowerShell is a much more capable language that things you can do fairly easily with it may be all but impossible to do in batch code. If feasible, I recommend switching to PowerShell altogether.

Comment: Yes, it is true. i already know that powershell is more advanced, modern and feature rich than batch.
many things are hard to do in batch, like this job, but easy in powershell.
When I've done something in Powershell, I'm curious to try it in batch. it's difficult, not as easy as in powershell.