# CMD.exe compatible replacement supporting longer command lines (>8191 chars)

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, command-line, limit

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation) of `cmd.exe` tells us there is a 8191 character limit to a cmd.exe command line. Powershell [may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354602/powershell-error-the-command-line-is-too-long) have the same issue (but anyway I think it is not compatible with cmd syntax).

The Windows OS technical limit is "much" higher, at 32767 caracters or so (see CreateProcessA [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa)).

Are there **compatible** alternative shells to `cmd.exe` that increase the command line length limit above 8191 characters ?

Note 1: I am **not** asking about a terminal emulator (GUI) problem: this is a shell problem.

Note 2: I believe this question is not a duplicate because it is focused on a precise limitation of `cmd.exe`. Also I could not post my `Yori` answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772/cmd-exe-replacement) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349022/alternative-windows-shells-besides-cmd-exe) questions because they are closed.

Comment: PowerShell is the dedicated successor of Windows Command Processor and does not have the command line length limitation of 8191 characters (in real bytes plus a terminating null byte). PowerShell requires indeed a different syntax to use. An application started by whatever shell interpreter is used must support also such long command lines on parsing the command line and creating the list of argument strings passed to function `main` of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Yori](http://www.malsmith.net/yori/). There is [no such limit](https://github.com/malxau/yori/issues/105) in Yori. Yori is open-source.

> Yori is a CMD replacement shell that supports backquotes, job control, and improves tab completion, file matching, aliases, command history, and more. It includes a handful of native Win32 tools that implement commonly needed tasks which can be used with any shell.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Take Command](https://jpsoft.com/products/take-command.html) from jpsoftware, abbreviated *TCC*. There is [no such limit](https://jpsoft.com/help/cmdlength.htm) in TCC.

> There is no limit to the size of a TCC command line (other than that imposed by Windows or the amount of RAM in the system).